# remote linking image and text

Tags: html, css

I have done days of research on this but have come across any solutions that fit exactly what I am trying to do. I feel that what I am trying to should be easily accomplished with just HTML and CSS but am running into difficulty.

I initially wanted text to appear when an image is click, pushing all the other content out of the way. This seemed to be too complicated and required some weird positioning tricks or for the text's space on the page just be empty until it appear (not what I want). Most solutions pointed to javascript but I want to use pure HTML and CSS.

I have given up on that so I am simply now trying to do this:

- Hover (but touch friendly) over an image and have that text be highlighted or stylized.

HTML:

```
<div class="left-photos">
    <a href="diane">
    <img id="diane-photo" src="diane.jpg" alt="diane profile photo" /></a>
</div>

<div class="us-profile-text">
    <h4>Diane Adamec - Board President</h4>
    <p>TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left-photos {
        width: 143px;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 10px;

    }

.us-profile-text p {
        padding: 0 5px 10px 5px;
        margin: 0;
    }

.us-profile-text {
    position: relative;
    font-size: .8em;
{

a:hover img {
        border: 5px solid #ff0000;
    }
```

I really do appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Correct, you can do it with just CSS, but you need to make sure the hidden content is nested within a parent `div` to do so. Otherwise, you'll need to use jQuery, which still isn't that bad.

## Pure HTML/CSS - [Working CodePen](http://codepen.io/bbennett/pen/azNrRy)

**HTML** (I changed your classes to make it easier to follow)

```
<div class="outer">
    <img id="diane-photo" src="http://animalia-life.com/data_images/dog/dog5.jpg" alt="diane profile photo" />
  <div class="lower"> <!-- NOTE THAT THIS DIV IS NESTED -->
      <h4>Diane Adamec - Board President</h4>
      <p>TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer {
  height:400px;
  width:100%;
}
.outer img {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
.lower {
  display:none;
}
.outer:hover .lower {
  display:block;
}
```

You mentioned it, but `hover` states won't solve your problem on mobile. If you want to use a click event, you're better off using jQuery, which could be something like this:

```
$(".outer").click(function() {
  $(".lower").css("display", "block")
})
```

Lots of ways to accomplish this, though. Good luck!

Comment: thanks so much for the start but your code doesn't seem to be hiding the text and doing anything on hovering? same thing with the code in codepen?

Comment: It's only doing the CSS version right now - displaying text below the image on hover only. If you want the jQuery to work, copy and paste the code here into the pen. It won't hide on a second click, though - you'll need a second method to do that.